# HAproxy redirects http to https only in private/incognito browser window

Tags: https, haproxy, http-redirect

I have a strange issue with redirecting http to https. I have 2 web servers and haproxy as a load balancer. I'm trying to setup the http redirection but it only works in private browser window.
Do you have any ideas why and how is that possible?

I have tried these configs in frontend and backend:
`http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }`
`http-request redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }`
`http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }`
`http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.
The resolution is to put the line

```
http-request redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

under frontend chapter.